# windows cmd to get default gateway address

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Is there away to extract default gateway ip address from following command output text (some thing like unix cut command) & store it in some variable and use that variable for further processing

```
C:\Users\Temp>ipconfig | findstr /i default | findstr /R [0-9]
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: @Compo can you link them here. i am new to batch programming and windows cmd.

Comment: The search text box in the header should be helpfull [default gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+default+gateway)